# PrimeNG Chips component using p-inputgroup challenge

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

First my code used simply String to define email but there were requirement to use multiple values instead of one String[]. I'm using PrimeNG 14.2.x combined with Angular 14 as frontend. Always with inputgroup using text have no problem but somehow it doesn't work well with p-chips component.

```
    <div class="p-col-12 p-md-4">
      <div class="p-inputgroup">
        <span class="p-inputgroup-addon"><em class="pi pi-envelope"></em></span>
        <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Email" name="recipientEmails">
      </div>
    </div>
```

result:
[browser view - ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWozt.png)

after modification I've got

```
    <div class="p-col-12 p-md-4">
      <div class="p-inputgroup">
        <span class="p-inputgroup-addon"><em class="pi pi-envelope"></em></span>
        <p-chips allowDuplicate="false" separator="," name="recipientEmails"></p-chips>
      </div>
    </div>
```

result:
[browser view - failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeYVA.png)

and from this point p-chips isn't useful anymore. User cannot see what is added.
I've stucked, Any ideas ?

I tried modify css directly to

```
.p-chips {
  width: 100%;
}
```

but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've resolved this by using bootstrap right now

```
<div class="p-col-12 p-md-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text"><em class="pi pi-envelope"></em></div>
    </div>
    <p-chips placeholder="Emails" allowDuplicate="false" separator="," name="recipientEmails"></p-chips>
  </div>
</div>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EkKX.png)

I hope it helps someone